# Making a partition query, reporting the first NOT NULL occurrence within partition before current row (if any)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `logins` table which looks like this:

```
person_id  |    login_at    |    points_won 
-----------+----------------+----------------------
 1         |   2017-02-02   |    
 1         |   2017-02-01   |    
 2         |   2017-02-01   |    2
 1         |   2017-01-29   |    2
 2         |   2017-01-28   |    
 2         |   2017-01-25   |    1
 3         |   2017-01-22   |    
 3         |   2017-01-21   |    
 1         |   2017-01-10   |    3
 1         |   2017-01-01   |    1
```

I want to generate a result set containing a `points_won` column, which should work something like: For each row partition based on the `person_id` order the partition by `login_at desc` then report the first occurrence (not null) of last_points_won of the ordered rows in the partition (if any).

It should result in something like this:

```
person_id  |    login_at    |    points_won        | last_points_won 
-----------+----------------+----------------------+----------------------
 1         |   2017-02-02   |                      |    2
 1         |   2017-02-01   |                      |    2
 2         |   2017-02-01   |      2               |    2
 1         |   2017-01-29   |      2               |    2
 2         |   2017-01-28   |                      |    1
 2         |   2017-01-25   |      1               |    1
 3         |   2017-01-22   |                      |    
 3         |   2017-01-21   |                      |    
 1         |   2017-01-10   |      3               |    3
 1         |   2017-01-01   |      1               |    1
```

**Or in plain words:**

> for each row, give me either the points won during this login OR if none, give
>   me the points won at the persons latest previous login, where he actually made some
>   points.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question?

Comment: `select l1.*, (select max(made_confirmation_at) from logins l2 where l1.person_id = l2.person_id) as last_confirmation_at from logins l1`

Comment: Hmm my example is bad, Can't use MAX() I'll correct it

Comment: **(1)** the example would be much clearer if it was ordered by person_id,login_at **(2)** You are looking for the **last** not null occurrence (which is not after the current row)

Comment: I updated the question now. I don't care about the order of the output, only that the values in last_points_won are "correct"

Comment: So, in other words, you want alternatives to the [`IGNORE NULLS` option of the `first_value()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) (which is not currently implemented in PostgreSQL)?

Comment: Hmm that sounds like it yes :-)

Comment: But maybe it wouldn't be done with that either, since it's the first NOT NULL value in the partition WHICH has a login_at <= the current rows!

Comment: Ok, but now I'm confused, because you wrote to order the partition by `login_at desc`, which means the current row has always lower `login_at` then others from its partition (so a row, which has *login_at <= the current row* couldn't be selected in any way).

Comment: Hehe, I know it's super hard for me to explain myself in code. I just tried doing it in "plain words" (see question update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved within a single window too, with the [`IGNORE NULLS` option of the `last_value()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html). But that's not supported in PostgreSQL yet. One alternative is the [`FILTER (WHERE ...)` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS), but that will only work, when the window function is an aggregate function in the first place (which is not true for `last_value()`, but [something similar could be created easily](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)) with [`CREATE AGGREGATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html)). To solve this with only built-in aggregates, you can use the `array_agg()` too:

```
SELECT (tbl).*,
       all_points_won[array_upper(all_points_won, 1)] last_points_won
FROM   (SELECT tbl,
               array_agg(points_won)
                 FILTER (WHERE points_won IS NOT NULL)
                 OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY login_at) all_points_won
        FROM   tbl) s
```

Note: the sub-query is not needed, if you create a dedicated `last_agg()` aggregate, like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION last_val(anyelement, anyelement)
  RETURNS anyelement
  LANGUAGE SQL
  IMMUTABLE
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  AS 'SELECT $2';

CREATE AGGREGATE last_agg(anyelement) (
  SFUNC = last_val,
  STYPE = anyelement
);

SELECT tbl.*,
       last_agg(points_won)
         FILTER (WHERE points_won IS NOT NULL)
         OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY login_at) last_points_won
FROM   tbl;
```

[Rextester sample](http://rextester.com/JDR67262)

**Edit:** once the `IGNORE NULLS` option will be supported on PostgreSQL, you can use the following query (which should work in Amazon Redshift too):

```
SELECT tbl.*,
       last_value(points_won IGNORE NULLS)
         OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY login_at ROW BETWEEN UNBOUNCED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) last_points_won
FROM   tbl;
```

Comment: Wohooooooo great!

Comment: Now comes the next question. Where this works fine on my 9.3 installation, it does not work for another database I have in Amazon Redshift (essentially postgresql 8 under the hood). It seems like the FILTER clause is not supported. Any other ideas? :-)

Comment: @NielsKristian Amazon Redshift is based on a really ancient PostgreSQL version, thus support very little of what PostgreSQL can achieve now. (And also that version is modded heavily with custom functions & disabled features). It is usually considered an entirely different database.

Comment: @NielsKristian but good news: it seems it supports the standard's [`IGNORE NULLS`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_first_value.html) option for the `last_value()` window function ;)

Comment: Wohooo, you are right again, BUT it needs a frame clause like: ROW BETWEEN UNBOUNCED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW

Comment: @NielsKristian yeah, probably that's also a difference between the 2 vendors. In PostgreSQL, that's the default range (when there is `ORDER BY`)

Answer (score 1):

```
select      *
           ,min(points_won) over
            (
                partition by person_id,group_id
            ) as last_points_won 

from       (select      *
                       ,count(points_won) over 
                        (
                            partition by person_id 
                            order by     login_at
                        ) as group_id

            from        mytable
            ) t
```

---

```
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| person_id | login_at   | points_won | group_id | last_points_won |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| 1         | 2017-01-01 | 1          | 1        | 1               |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| 1         | 2017-01-10 | 3          | 2        | 3               |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| 1         | 2017-01-29 | 2          | 3        | 2               |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| 1         | 2017-02-01 | (null)     | 3        | 2               |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| 1         | 2017-02-02 | (null)     | 3        | 2               |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| 2         | 2017-01-25 | 1          | 1        | 1               |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| 2         | 2017-01-28 | (null)     | 1        | 1               |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| 2         | 2017-02-01 | 2          | 2        | 2               |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| 3         | 2017-01-21 | (null)     | 0        | (null)          |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| 3         | 2017-01-22 | (null)     | 0        | (null)          |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Sorry, I was just updating my example, it was bad, and I can't use MAX

Comment: See updated answer. I left he group_id so it would be easier to understand